# How to search facebook groups from my app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

I want to show selected results from within a facebook group in my app but I cant seem to figure out how to do that. I have tried playing with "fb://group/{id}" intent with no success. It opens the group page in facebook app but if I try adding some extra parameters e.g "fb://group/{id}/search/?query=some_text" it starts the facebook app on its home screen. I assume this is because the uri is malformed. But I don't see any other method. There is a supported uri for search i.e "fb://search" but I cant seem to find any information about it.

Answer (score -1):

The only way I know how to do it is to open the app, go into the menu, at at the very bottom in small letters it says View Desktop Site (or something to that effect). It doesn't even look like a link - but it is - and it will open the full version of FB in your browser. Then you can navigate as normal (including search). Hope this helps!